# Registry entry /Microsoft SQL Server/Instance Names/SQL does not list all installed instances

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve the installation folder for SQL Server instances. I'm trying to do this by accessing the

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/Instance Names/SQL
```

entry to find the installed instances. However, not all the instances are listed here, even though they are running.
Also, the MSSQL11.[INSTANCENAME] entry is missing in

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/
```

I've noticed this on a machine with 2 2012 instances and a machine with a 2005 and a 2012 machine. Does the bitness of the SQL Server installation matter here?
Am I looking in the correct location?
Are there times where they will not be listed here?

Thanks

Comment: That's the right place. What versions and editions are you missing? Can you connect to those missing instances and run SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_registry to see what their regkeys are?

Comment: @SQLmojoe On the machine with 2 2012 instances, it's missing the default instance and on the other, it's missing the 2005 isntance (SQLExpress). Though I think I found the issue, I don't know why, but the 64 bit and 32 bit registries show different instances. They are both running 32 bit instances on a 64 bit machine, so I would think they'd be in the same locations.Thanks